# Generating Python interpreter-intolerant wheels from a `pyproject.toml`

Tags: python, pyproject.toml

Consider the following `pyproject.toml`:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=40.8.0", "wheel"]
[project]
name = "foo"
version = "0.0.0"
requires-python = "~=3.9"
```

If I run `pip wheel .` in the directory containing this file, then I generate a wheel named `foo-0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl`. However, this wheel filename indicates that any python3 interpreter is fine, yet my `requires-python` metadata in my `pyproject.toml` indicates that only python3.9 is acceptable.

How can I get the `requires-python` metadata to be reflected in the wheel? I would expect the wheel filename to be `foo-0.0.0-cp39-cp39-any.whl` in this case. . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not quite what the platform tag in the wheel filename is used for - cp39 would indicate that you're only compatible with *CPython* 3.9 or higher, and this wheel should not be selected by PyPy or some other implementations. You would usually only use a compatibility tag like that if you had some compiled C extensions inside the wheel that are CPython-specific.

The [*Requires-Python*](https://peps.python.org/pep-0345/#requires-python) metadata is still located *inside* your built wheel, which you'll see if you try to install it on an incompatible Python version:

```
$ python3.8 -m pip install ./foo-0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
Processing ./foo-0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
ERROR: Package 'foo' requires a different Python: 3.8.13 not in '~=3.9'
```

The location of the metadata is here:

```
$ unzip foo-0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
Archive:  foo-0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
  inflating: foo-0.0.0.dist-info/METADATA  
  inflating: foo-0.0.0.dist-info/WHEEL  
  inflating: foo-0.0.0.dist-info/top_level.txt  
  inflating: foo-0.0.0.dist-info/RECORD  
$ grep Requires foo-0.0.0.dist-info/METADATA
Requires-Python: ~=3.9
```

As for how this works with PyPI - the index may return this metadata in the [json API](https://peps.python.org/pep-0691/) ([example](https://pypi.org/pypi/setuptools/json)) and in the [simple API](https://peps.python.org/pep-0503/) ([example](https://pypi.org/simple/setuptools/))<sup>†</sup>. That allows pip to avoid downloading and unpacking incompatible wheels.

<sup>†</sup> <sub>It's in a `data-requires-python` attribute of the href - you might have to "view-source" in your browser to see it.</sub>

Comment: Ah, I do have a cpython extension  . . . that said I've never seen anyone use anything other than cpython.

Comment: If you have a platform-specific extensions you may want to look into specifying the `plat_name` option to the [`bdist_wheel`](https://github.com/pypa/wheel) setuptools extension.